# Ruby Extra key for message in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having below JSON response, I want to add a message key. How I can insert it.

```
{

  "bundle_deals": [
    {
      "id": 60,
      "service_category_id": 5,
      "service_provider_id": 12,
      "title": "Voice + Internet",
      "short_description": "Internet speeds up to 75Mbps.\r\nUnlimited calling",

    }

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert JSON into a hash and then just add a key to the hash.

```
   require 'json'
   hash = JSON.parse(value) 
   hash.message_key = "your message key"
```